# Given a sequence of words, print all anagrams together

Tags: c, algorithm, strings, interview-questions

> Given an array of words, print all anagrams together. For example, if
>   the given array is {“cat”, “dog”, “tac”, “god”, “act”}, then output
>   may be “cat tac act dog god”.

My idea is to sort individual words firstly. And then sort the array of words.
In this way, the anagrams will be together. The following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct word_with_ind
{
    char* word;
    int ind;
}*word_with_ind_ptr;

int comp_char(const void* x, const void* y)
{
    char* c1 = (char*)x;
    char* c2 = (char*)y;

    return *c1 - *c2;
}

int comp_str(const void* x, const void* y)
{
    const word_with_ind_ptr w1 = (word_with_ind_ptr)x;
    const word_with_ind_ptr w2 = (word_with_ind_ptr)y;

    return strcmp(w1->word, w2->word);
}

void destroy(word_with_ind_ptr x, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        free(x[i].word);
    }
    free(x);
}

void print_anagrams_together(char* word[], int size)
{
    //make a copy of the original word array. And sort
    //the individual words
    word_with_ind_ptr x = (word_with_ind_ptr)malloc(sizeof(struct word_with_ind)*size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        x[i].ind = i;
        x[i].word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(word[i])+1));
        strcpy(x[i].word, word[i]);
        qsort(x[i].word, strlen(x[i].word), sizeof(char), comp_char);
    }

    //sort the array of words
    qsort(x, size, sizeof(struct word_with_ind), comp_str);

    //print result
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", word[x[i].ind]);
    }

    //free memory
    destroy(x, size);

}



int main()
{
    char* word[] = {"cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"};
    int size = sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0]);
    print_anagrams_together(word, size);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FiHopZz, your concept seems fine.   A few comments:

- in general, don't typedef pointers. It is confusing.
- your functions are not const-correct. In other words they cast const values
  to non-const values.  The compiler will warn you of this if you enable
  warnings.
- I prefer pointers to be declared like this: `char *p`, not `char* p`.
  Consider `char* a, b` if in doubt (`b` is not a pointer but looks as if it
  should be).
- all local functions should be declared `static`
- print_anagrams_together should take a const word array and a size_t size
  (`destroy` should also take `size_t` not `int`)
- don't cast the return from `malloc` and note that malloc can fail.
- sizeof(char) is 1 by definition.
- use `strdup` to copy a word, not malloc.  strdup can also fail.
- you took the length of the string twice, once in the `malloc` call and once
  in the `qsort` call.
- you also used `strcpy` on a string of which you already knew the
  length. `memcpy` is better (but remember to copy length+1).
- print_anagrams_together is arguably better broken into several
  sub-functions: `copy_words`, `sort_words`, `print_words`.  Well done for making
  `destroy` as function.  This  would be renamed `destroy_words` for symmetry.
- arguably, `copy_words` and `sort_words` above could be combined.  This is how
  your loop is written, with a word copied and then sorted in the same loop.
  This is clearly slightly more efficient, but in some way it does not appeal
  to me.  For a start what do you call it? - `copy_and_sort_words` is rather
  ugly. But also a copy_words that just duplicates the array is easily tested;
  one that duplicates it **and** modifies it is not.  These are perhaps not
  considerations that belong to a simple program such as this, but they are
  worth beaaring in mind for more complicated tasks.
- comments should be useful. Yours are mainly noise.  If nothing needs
  saying, say nothing.
- the `word` array in `main` should be `const`
- the `size` in `main` should be `const size_t`, not `int`
- `main` should have a parameter list

Don't take my comments on breaking your `print_anagrams_together` into separate
functions too seriously. It is not a big function and it is easily understood.
Breaking it apart would probably make the program worse.  However, for bigger
or more complicated applications, having several loops in the same function
in my opinion often indicates a lack of proper subdivision.  Just my opinion
though and others may differ.

Note also that although I say that malloc/strdup can fail, they are of course
unlikely to fail in a small program like this.  You might say that it is
pointless testing for NULL pointers when you know they will probably be okay.
The only thing you can sensibly do is to print an error and exit anyway
(`perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`).  But it is a good discipline always
to check the return values of functions that can fail.  Just do it.

Comment: Another issue - don't bother to allocate memory on the heap, if you release it in scope.

Comment: Good comments. Just a few things: "`I prefer pointers to be declared like this: char *p, not char* p`". This is subjective coding style, you cannot easily say that one form is better than the other. "`use strdup`", I disagree, strdup is not standard C.

Comment: That is why I said "I prefer" rather than "you should" :-)  On `strdup`, really? The OP had three issues with his use of `malloc` to copy a single string and that is not uncommon. Can it really be preferable to `strdup`, standard or not?

Comment: @avip, In the function `print_anagrams_together`, If I don't use `malloc` to allocate memory, how should I do? You can't allocate memory statically.

Comment: @FihopZz: My apologies, I got too used to c99.